# always_null member in jffs2 structs

Tags: c, linux, struct, filesystems, jffs2

Looking through the `jffs2` code in Linux, I noticed that first member in two structs in `xattr.h` is the same and it is `void *always_null`.
Here is one of the structs:

```
struct jffs2_xattr_datum
{
    void *always_null;
    struct jffs2_raw_node_ref *node;
    uint8_t class;
    uint8_t flags;
    uint16_t xprefix;

    struct list_head xindex;
    atomic_t refcnt;
    uint32_t xid;
    uint32_t version;

    uint32_t data_crc;
    uint32_t hashkey;
    char *xname;
    uint32_t name_len;
    char *xvalue;
    uint32_t value_len;
};
```

I am wondering why this member is created and what it is used for.

Comment: If this has something to do with flash programming, perhaps the first few bytes are reserved for system use (a vector?)